Although C++ program compiles with no error at runtime I take std::bad_alloc
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class F>
struct I
{
 F _f;
 I(F f):_f(f){}
};

template<class F>
struct C
{
  F _f;
 C(F f):_f(f){}
};

template<class F>
struct S
{
 F _f;
 std::string _s;
 S(std::string const& s,F f):_s(s),_f(f)
 {
   
 }
};

C c(std::string("."));
S s1(std::string(",Char: "),c);
I i(s1);
S s2(std::string("Int: "),i);

std::string _sprintf(std::string const& prefix,std::string const& str)
{
  return prefix+str;
}

template<class A>
auto _sprintf(std::string const& prefix,I<A> const& a)
{
  return [&](int i){ return _sprintf(prefix+std::to_string(i),a._f);};
}

template<class A>
auto _sprintf(std::string const& prefix,C<A> const& a)
{
  return [&](char c){return _sprintf(prefix + std::string(1,c),a._f);};

}
template<class A>
auto _sprintf(std::string const& prefix,S<A> const& a)
{
  return _sprintf(prefix + a._s,a._f);
}
template<class Fmt>
auto sprintf(Fmt const& fmt)
{
  return _sprintf("",fmt);
}

int main()
{
auto test = sprintf(s2);
std::cout<<test(5)('x');
}

I try to create a type safe sprintf. I have taken the example from a Haskell paper and I tried to convert it to C++. The compiler does not complain but at runtime I take
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)  ./printf

So you want something like std::format? Or the library the standard was based on?

Don't use names that start with underscore. They are reserved for compiler use. In particular, I'd expect _[standard library name] to be used by compiler for some internal implementation.

You have _sprintf() return a lambda that captures local stack variables by reference, and then call them later after the lifetime of stack-frame.  Welcome to C++ and undefined behaviour.

Python is a garbage collected language, C++ is not. In C++ holding a reference to something does not keep it alive. Changing [&] to [=] would avoid this problem, but whether this would have some other problems in your code I don't know.

marko and @john gave me the solution. By changing [&] to [=] the program run successfully. Thank you. If you want write your answer separately not in the comment section to get the accepted answer mark.

The temporary prefix + a._s created in the statement return _sprintf(prefix + a._s,a._f); is destructed at the end-of-statement ;.  The capture by reference outlives the temporary variable.  When the already destructed temporary is later dereferenced, hilarity ensues.

Just because your program compiles doesn't mean you can't have logical mistakes. In this case, you have memory errors. Memory errors in C++ can show up far from their source. Tools like address sanitizer can help catch memory problems at their source. In this case, address sanitizer tells the following:
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return on address 0x71e077b000b0 at pc 0x71e07a0794b6 bp 0x7ffc765a61f0 sp 0x7ffc765a59b0
READ of size 5 at 0x71e077b000b0 thread T0
    #0 0x71e07a0794b5 in memcpy (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xfa4b5) (BuildId: e522418529ce977df366519db3d02a8fbdfe4494)
    #1 0x71e079e6b8c1 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0x15e8c1) (BuildId: 998334304023149e8c44e633d4a2c69800a2eb79)
    #2 0x4042b2 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:3691
    #3 0x4030f0 in _sprintf<S<C<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, I<S<C<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)::{lambda(int)#1}::operator()(int) const /app/example.cpp:42
    #4 0x40251c in main /app/example.cpp:65
    #5 0x71e079829d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: 490fef8403240c91833978d494d39e537409b92e)
    #6 0x71e079829e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: 490fef8403240c91833978d494d39e537409b92e)
    #7 0x402334 in _start (/app/output.s+0x402334) (BuildId: 1fd827987fb5ef5739ae395faa6d440683767fc7)

https://godbolt.org/z/EE8sd5cqK
stack-use-after-return is generally a dangling reference problem. The _sprintf("",fmt); call creates a temporary std::string that binds to the std::string const& prefix parameter. The prefix is captured by reference but that temporary dies at the end of sprintf, leaving the returned lambda with a dangling reference. To fix this problem you can capture by value:
template<class A>
auto _sprintf(std::string const& prefix,I<A> const& a)
{
  return [prefix, &a](int i){ return _sprintf(prefix+std::to_string(i),a._f);};
}

template<class A>
auto _sprintf(std::string const& prefix,C<A> const& a)
{
  return [prefix, &a](char c){return _sprintf(prefix + std::string(1,c),a._f);};
}

As a side note: Generally you can and should avoid const std::string& in C++ and use std::string_view instead. Similar lifetime care is needed with std::string_view, still.
